# Error Using fviz_nbClust for Kmean Clustering

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 2 rows and 24 columns, and i´m tryng to use the command :

```
fviz_nbclust(Data, kmeans, method = "wss")
```

But when i use it, the following error appears:

```
Error: number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)
```

Comment: This is for obtaining the k for the kmean.

Comment: A dataset with 2 rows is not going to have any cluster structure. Try adding more rows.

Answer (score 5):

Although I agree with @TTNK, when I faced the same problem with my data, I found that a proper setting of parameter `k.max` in `fviz_nbclust` is the solution. For instance, try a value for `k.max` lower than the number of rows of your dataset.

Comment: I wish the person who asked this question will thick this as the right answer1